# Cache the email address and password in google Doc API in iPhone App

Tags: iphone, ios

I am using the Google Document Api to upload my Document to my google account through my iPhone App but the problem is that every time i use the App Google Api ask for email address and password i want to cache my email address and password so that is don't ask me to re-enter it again is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

For something this simple, you can use NSUserDefaults. You can do this anywhere you need to:

To save your info:

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userDefaults setString:@"GDocsPW"];
[userDefaults setString:@"GDocsUserName"];
[userDefaults synchronize];
```

To retrieve the info:

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
self.yourGDocsPassword = [userDefaults stringForKey:@"GDocsPW"];
self.yourGDocsUsername = [userDefaults stringForKey:@"GDocsUserName"];
```